# How to install regular python (via homebrew) and miniconda in the same computer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, homebrew

I downloaded conda, however I would like to use pip and a regular python version (homebrew) for a different purpose, is it ok if I install python and pip via brew and then I install conda?

**Update**

after installing miniconda I tried to install python via homebrew and both python versions crashed. How can I install miniconda and then python via homebrew?

Comment: No problem at all.

Comment: Do you think both interpreters can crash if I installed them in the same computer?

Comment: is there a crash error message?

Comment: When I tried to run conda after installing homebrew python conda didnt recognize the path

Comment: I think that the troubleshooting docs at https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#programs-fail-due-to-invoking-conda-python-instead-of-system-python addresses a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

[Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/conda-data-science/?lang=en):

> Conda creates language-agnostic environments natively whereas pip
>   relies on `virtualenv` to manage only Python environments Though it is
>   recommended to always use `conda` packages, `conda` also includes pip,
>   so you don’t have to choose between the two. For example, to install a
>   python package that does not have a `conda` package, but is available
>   through pip.

You can also use `pip` within your `conda` environment:

```
conda install pip
pip <pip command>
```

or

```
conda install -n testenv pip
source activate testenv
pip <pip command>
```

You can also add pip to default packages of any environment so it is present each time so you don't have to follow the above snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The thing is that I am working with conda for a specific task. However, I prefer to use my own python3/homebrew configuration, which I actually will use it for another purposes... Do you think its safe to install conda and python via homebrew separately in the same laptop?

Comment: I think it's ok, they store objects in separated areas as well.

Comment: You may consider using PyEnv (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage different Python versions.

Comment: Just to save a lot of other people some heartache, using pyenv with conda can create a bad state on your machine.  If you conda install utilities like ncurses, they install a shim in pyenv that will not work unless you have miniconda active.  Things like tput and clear and ... stop working because your PATH is wacky now.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2019, Amit Singh's comment is slightly out of date (and the link is broken). I had the same issue previously, but needed to install conda to work on a specific project with a collaborator. I did this using miniconda, but it should work with Anaconda as well.

After installing conda, this is added to ~/.bash_profile (or .bashrc):

```
added by Miniconda3 4.5.12 installer
>>> conda init >>>
!! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/<user>/miniconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/<user>/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/<user>/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/<user>/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
<<< conda init <<<
```

It basically automatically activates a base conda environment and puts you in it when you start a new shell. This adds conda's python, and other software, to your path. Any tools looking for system/homebrew install programs such as python will get the conda versions instead if they exist. This can create problems if you are trying to use the homebrew versions of things.

This whole block can be safely deleted. Instead, add:

```
. /Users/<user>/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

to you ~./bash_profile. This calls a script which creates bash functions for conda, conda activate, and conda deactivate and sets some environment variables. Importantly, it doesn't active the base environment (the default, global conda environment) or change your path.

You can now create a conda environment for your project and install whatever you need into that:

```
conda create -n my_project python R jupyter # Whatever packages you need
conda activate my_project
# do some stuff
conda deactivate # leave the environment
# do unrelated stuff without issues
```

If you do want to use the default (root) environment, it can be activated like any other:

```
conda activate root
# do some stuff
conda deactivate
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

For MacOS just use `. "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"` or what will be after **then**.

Answer (score 2):

From [Anaconda Troubleshoot FAQ](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#programs-fail-due-to-invoking-conda-python-instead-of-system-python), following methods can be employed :

- Edit your `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` files so that the conda binary directory, such as `~/miniconda3/bin`, is no longer added to the PATH environment variable. You can still run `conda` `activate` and `deactivate` by using their full path names, such as `~/miniconda3/bin/conda`.
- You may also create a folder with symbolic links to `conda`, `activate` and `deactivate`, and then edit your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file to add this folder to your PATH. If you do this, running `python` will invoke the system Python, but running `conda` commands, `source activate MyEnv`, `source activate root`, or `source deactivate` will work normally.
  After running `source activate` to activate any environment, including after running `source activate root`, running `python` will invoke the Python in the active conda environment.